# How to write `height : self.minimum_height` for BoxLayout in .py file -- kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am struck with a problem. I have a BoxLayout whose height was set to self.minimum_height in .kv file . However i was getting an error that `Nonetype Object has no attribute 'add_widget'` where `Nonetype` basically refers to the BoxLayout . The problem arised when i started using Screens. However I suppose it is just a bug of kivy (Please correct me if I am wrong) . So i wrote the code in .py file and when i thought of using the `self.minimum_height` for BoxLayout i remembered that in .py file `self.` refers to the FloatLayout(that's the class I inherited) .So then I tried using Clock to schedule a function to update The BoxLayout's height that repeats itself at rate of 300 per sec. Though it work fine but whenever their was an increase increases the size of the Boxlayout **{i have few textinputs in the Boxlayout which has y_scroll so they causes an increase in Boxlayout}** the entire screen would shake up and I wanna avoid such problem.. So is their a better way to run `height = self.minimum_height` for BoxLayout without such glitches in .py file...

codes i tried:

```
def modifyy(self,dt):
    self.boxxy = self.boxxy.minimum_height
Clock.schedule_interval(self.modiffy , 1/300)
```

and in kivy it was

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation : 'vertical'
    size_hint : 1,None
    height : self.minimum_height
```

Edited : Added my code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Main(FloatLayout):

    def modify_update(self,dt):                       #this is the method
        self.boxxy.height = self.boxxy.minimum_height #

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.modify_update, 1/300) #this method

        self.main_body_card = MDCard(pos_hint = {'x':0.056 , 'top':0.836}, size_hint = (0.88,0.82))
        self.add_widget(self.main_body_card)

        self.scrlv_main = ScrollView(do_scroll_y = True , do_scroll_x = False , bar_width = 10)
        self.main_body_card.add_widget(self.scrlv_main)

        self.boxxy = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical' , size_hint = (1,None) , spacing = 15 ,padding = 55)
        self.scrlv_main.add_widget(self.boxxy)
        #self.boxxy.height = self.boxxy.minimum_height

        self.obj_1_ = MDTextField(size_hint = (0.7,None),mode = 'rectangle',multiline = True)
        self.boxxy.add_widget(self.obj_1_)
        self.obj_1_.hint_text = 'Box 1   '

        self.obj_2_ = MDTextField(size_hint = (0.7,None),mode = 'rectangle',multiline = True)
        self.boxxy.add_widget(self.obj_2_)
        self.obj_2_.hint_text = 'Box 2    '

class MinimalExecutableCode(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

MinimalExecutableCode().run()
```

Any help is quite apperciated

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: here u go bro . try entering some stuff in the field and press enter ..u can see that the box shakes like anything for 0.1s maybe

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not aware of any problems with using `height: self.minimum_height` in `kv` with or without `Screens`. I suggest posting another question with your code that displays that problem.

As far as using `self.minimum_height` in python, a better approach would be to just call your `modify_update()` method when it is needed (just as using it in `kv` would do). Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
# from kivy.clock import Clock

class Main(FloatLayout):

    # Note the modified args
    def modify_update(self, *args):                       #this is the method
        print('update height')
        self.boxxy.height = self.boxxy.minimum_height #

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #  Do not call this method when it is not needed
        # Clock.schedule_interval(self.modify_update, 1/300) #this method

        self.main_body_card = MDCard(pos_hint = {'x':0.056 , 'top':0.836}, size_hint = (0.88,0.82))
        self.add_widget(self.main_body_card)

        self.scrlv_main = ScrollView(do_scroll_y = True , do_scroll_x = False , bar_width = 10)
        self.main_body_card.add_widget(self.scrlv_main)

        self.boxxy = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical' , size_hint = (1,None) , spacing = 15 ,padding = 55)
        self.scrlv_main.add_widget(self.boxxy)
        #self.boxxy.height = self.boxxy.minimum_height

        self.obj_1_ = MDTextField(size_hint = (0.7,None),mode = 'rectangle',multiline = True)
        self.boxxy.add_widget(self.obj_1_)
        self.obj_1_.hint_text = 'Box 1   '
        self.obj_1_.bind(height=self.modify_update)  # call modify_update() when this MDTextField changes size

        self.obj_2_ = MDTextField(size_hint = (0.7,None),mode = 'rectangle',multiline = True)
        self.boxxy.add_widget(self.obj_2_)
        self.obj_2_.hint_text = 'Box 2    '
        self.obj_2_.bind(height=self.modify_update)  # call modify_update() when this MDTextField changes size

class MinimalExecutableCode(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

MinimalExecutableCode().run()
```

Comment: But can i plz know what does the `*arg` did here ..

Comment: That is just a way to allow the method to be called with any number of arguments (or none). You can replace it with the actual arguments like this: `def modify_update(self, changed_widget, new_height):`.

Answer (score 0):

Of the several questions and answers on this topic, I didn't find one that showed how to get relative sizing in a scrollview application without using size_hint. I started from the example shown in the answer below, but rather than bind a callback to each of the individual widgets of the child layout of the scrollview, I found it easier to bind a single callback to the parent of the scrollview. Once in that callback, with the size of the parent known, it is possible to calculate the absolute sizes to achieve a relative sizing of a) the scrollview and b) the content in the scrollview. The latter for example, to get an integer number of rows in a scrollable table.